# Perl "Not an ARRAY reference" error

Tags: perl, hash

I'll be glad if someone can enlighten me as to my mistake:

```
my %mymap; 
@mymap{"balloon"} = {1,2,3};

print $mymap{"balloon"}[0] . "\n";
```

Comment: You really need to read some documentation on Perl and Perl data structures: read [`perldoc perlintro`](http://p3rl.org/intro), [`perldoc perldata`](http://p3rl.org/data) and probably [`perldoc perlreftut`](http://p3rl.org/reftut) and [`perldoc perldsc`](http://p3rl.org/dsc) as well.

Comment: Further there are books available like [`Modern Perl`](http://onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/) available. Please learn the language basics and come back to us when you have bugs and we will be glad to help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you had used 'use strict; use warnings;' on the top of your code you probably have had better error messages.

What you're doing is creating a hash called *mymap*. A hash stores data as key => value pairs.
You're then assigning an array reference to the key *balloon*. Your small code snipped had two issues: 1. you did not addressed the mymap hash, 2. if you want to pass a list, you should use square brackets:

```
my %mymap;
$mymap{"balloon"} = [1,2,3];
print $mymap{"balloon"}[0] . "\n";
```

this prints '1'.

You can also just use an array:

```
my @balloon = (1,2,3);
print $balloon[0] . "\n";
```

Answer (score 6):

`$mymap{'balloon'}` is a *hash* not an *array*. The expression `{1,2,3}` creates a hash:

```
 {
   '1' => 2,
   '3' => undef
 }
```

You assigned it to a *slice* of `%mymap` corresponding to the *list* of keys: `('balloon')`. Since the key *list* was 1 item and the value *list* was one item, you did the same thing as

```
$mymap{'balloon'} = { 1 => 2, 3 => undef };
```

If you had used `strict` and `warnings` it would have clued you in to your error. I got:

`Scalar value @mymap{"balloon"} better written as $mymap{"balloon"} at - line 3.`
 `Odd number of elements in anonymous hash at - line 3.`

Answer (score 3):

Well, first off, always `use strict; use warnings;`. If you had, it might have told you about what is wrong here.

Here's what you do in your program:

```
my %mymap;  # declare hash %mymap
@mymap{"balloon"} = {1,2,3};  # attempt to use a hash key on an undeclared 
                              # array slice and assign an anonymous hash to it

print $mymap{"balloon"}[0] . "\n";  # print the first element of a scalar hash value
```

For it to do what you expect, do:

```
my %mymap = ( 'balloon' => [ 1,2,3 ] );
print $mymap{'balloon'}[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, a few things...

`%mymap` is a hash.  `$mymap{"balloon"}` is a scalar--namely, the value of the hash `%mymap` corresponding to the key `"balloon"`.  `@mymap{"balloon"}` is an attempt at what's called a hash slice--basically, you can use these to assign a bunch of values to a bunch of keys at once:  `@hash{@keys}=@values`.

So, if you want to assign an array reference to `$mymap{"balloon"}`, you'd need something like:

`$mymap{"balloon"}=[1,2,3]`.

To access the elements, you can use `->` like so:

```
$mymap{"balloon"}->[0] #equals 1
$mymap{"balloon"}->[1] #equals 2
$mymap{"balloon"}->[2] #equals 3
```

Or, you can omit the arrows:  `$mymap{"balloon"}[0]`, etc.

Comment: N.B. Between indexes you may omit the arrow operator `->` as per the "Arrow Rule" in [`perldoc perlreftut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html#Arrow-Rule) to say `$mymap{ballon}[0]`

Comment: Yeah, I personally prefer using the arrows, since (IMO) they allow an easier visual demarcation of the layers in the data.  Since TIMTOWTDI, however, I've made an edit.

Comment: I understand and even support that point, however once you have several indexes lined up most readers should see that it is a nested data structure and be ok with it. BTW I do usually still use an arrow when the data contained is a coderef that I am invoking.